# Рекурсивно обойти папки и из файлов json и csv получить информацию о станциях метро, после создать json файл по образцу

Tags: java, json, рекурсия, csv

Нужно написать программу, которая получает

- HTML-код страницы «Список станций Московского метрополитена» с помощью    библиотеки jsoup.
- Парсит полученную страницу и получает из неё:
  линии московского метро (имя и номер линии, цвет не нужен);
  станции московского метро (имя станции и номер линии).
- Собирает данные о станциях метро — даты их открытия и глубину станций — из файлов формата CSV и JSON, обходя папки, лежащие в архиве. Разархивируйте архив и напишите код, который будет обходить все вложенные папки, искать в папках файлы JSON и CSV и обрабатывать их в зависимости от формата. Метод для обхода папок должен принимать путь до папки в которой надо производить поиск.
- Создаёт и записывает на диск два JSON-файла:
  Файл со списком станций по линиям и списком линий по формату JSON-файла из проекта SPBMetro (файл map.json)
  Файл stations.json со свойствами станций в следующем формате:

  {
  "station": [
  {
  "name": "Ленинский поспект",
  "line": "Калужской - Рижская",
  "date": "13.10.1962",
  "depth": "-16",
  "hasConnection": true
  },
  {
  .......
  },
  ]
  }

По первому json файлу всё понятно, с html разобралась, json собран. Для создания второго файла и рекурсивного обхода создала класс DataCollector. Собираю данные из файлов в Map<String,Station> listStations.

Класс Station

```
package core;

public class Station implements Comparable<Station>{
    private String numberLine;
    private String name;
    private String lineName;
    private String date;
    private String depth;
    private boolean hasConnection;

    public Station(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Station(String name, String lineName, String date, String depth, boolean hasConnection) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lineName = lineName;
        this.date = date;
        this.depth = depth;
        this.hasConnection = hasConnection;
    }

    public Station(String name, String numberLine) {
        this.name = name;
        this.numberLine = numberLine;
    }

    public String getLineName() {
        return lineName;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public String getDepth() {
        return depth;
    }

    public boolean isHasConnection() {
        return hasConnection;
    }

    public String getNumberLine() {
        return numberLine;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setNumberLine(String numberLine) {
        this.numberLine = numberLine;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setLineName(String lineName) {
        this.lineName = lineName;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public void setDepth(String depth) {
        this.depth = depth;
    }

    public void setHasConnection(boolean hasConnection) {
        this.hasConnection = hasConnection;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Station station) {
        int lineComparison = numberLine.compareToIgnoreCase(station.getNumberLine());
        if(lineComparison != 0) {
            return lineComparison;
        }
        return name.compareToIgnoreCase(station.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return compareTo((Station) obj) == 0;
    }
}
```

Класс DataCollector

```
import core.Station;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class DataCollector {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DataCollector{" +
                "listStations=" + listStations +
                '}';
    }

    Map<String,Station> listStations = new HashMap<>();
    String DATA_FILE = "";

    public Map<String, Station> getListStations() {
        return listStations;
    }

    public Map<String, Station> fileReader(String path) throws ParseException, FileNotFoundException {
        File doc = new File(path);
        if (doc.isFile()) {
            DATA_FILE = doc.getAbsolutePath();
            if (doc.getName().endsWith(".json")) {
                getDatesFromJson(doc);   //!!!!
            }

            if (doc.getName().endsWith(".csv")) {
               getDatesFromCsv(doc);
            }
        }
        else {
            File[] files = doc.listFiles();
            for (File file : files) {
                fileReader(file.getAbsolutePath()); //!!!!!!
            }
        }

        return listStations;
    }

    private void getDatesFromJson(File doc) throws ParseException {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONArray jsonData = (JSONArray) parser.parse(getJsonFile());
        for (Object it : jsonData) {
            JSONObject stationJsonObject = (JSONObject) it;
            String stationName = (String) stationJsonObject.get("station_name");
            if (!listStations.containsKey(stationName)) {
                listStations.put(stationName, new Station(stationName));
            }
            if (doc.getName().startsWith("dates")) {
                String date = (String) stationJsonObject.get("dates");
                listStations.get(stationName).setDate(date);
            } else if (doc.getName().startsWith("depths")) {
                String depth = (String) stationJsonObject.get("depth_meters");
                listStations.get(stationName).setDepth(depth); // !!!вот здесь выдаёт ошибку 
            }
            
        }
    }

    private void getDatesFromCsv(File doc) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String filePath = doc.getAbsolutePath();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath)); //filePath
        try {
            String splitBy = ",";
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] lines = line.split(splitBy);
                for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                    if (i % 2 == 0) {
                        String stationName = lines[i];
                        if (!listStations.containsKey(stationName)) {
                            listStations.put(stationName, new Station(stationName));
                        }
                        if (doc.getName().startsWith("dates")) {
                            listStations.get(stationName).setDate(lines[++i]);
                        } else if (doc.getName().startsWith("depth")) {
                            listStations.get(stationName).setDepth(lines[++i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String getJsonFile() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(DATA_FILE));
            lines.forEach(line -> builder.append(line));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

}
```

При запуске Debug все файлы читаются и данные благополучно сохраняются в listStations. А при запуске main выбрасывает вот что:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Long cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.lang.Long and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at DataCollector.getDatesFromJson(DataCollector.java:69)
    at DataCollector.fileReader(DataCollector.java:39)
    at DataCollector.fileReader(DataCollector.java:49)
    at Main.main(Main.java:31)
```

В методе getDatesFromJson отметила строку с этим исключением и строки, где этом метод вызывается.
Что не так??

Вот ссылка на github
https://github.com/AnBogdanova/FilesAndNetworks/tree/master/FilesAndNetwork/Data__Collector

Comment: вы бы хотя бы указали где эти строчки 69, 39, 49 что в стэктрейсе находятся

Comment: ArchDemon
 Сорри))) Отметила строки вот так  //!!!

Comment: На гитхабе строчка 69 у вас `Long depth = (Long) stationJsonObject.get("depth_meters");`, а здесь 69 строчка это `String depth = (String) stationJsonObject.get("depth_meters");`. Где актуальнее?

Comment: Ошибка на строчку выше. Попробуйте написать так: `String depth = String.valueOf(stationJsonObject.get("depth_meters"));`.

Comment: Vadik, сработало!! Заменила, cпасибо!